# Initializing the height of a textarea based on the content using a knockout data-bind

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js, textarea, expand

I am currently expanding and collapsing the height of a text area on the `keyup`event. However I want the text area also to initialise it's height once the value is binded to the text area via a knockout custom binding. Any solutions?
**(With the use of only javascript) (Without adding any jquery libraries)**

**Current key up handelling code**

```
var textElement = $textBox.get(0);
var textElementOriginalHeight = $textBox.height();

while ($textBox.height() > textElementOriginalHeight && textElement.scrollHeight < textElement.offsetHeight) {
                $textBox.height($textBox.height() - 1);
            }

            var h = 0;

            while (textElement.scrollHeight > textElement.offsetHeight && h !== textElement.offsetHeight) {
                h = textElement.offsetHeight;
                $textBox.height($textBox.height() + 1);
            }
```

Comment: Show your current `keyup` handling code.

Comment: Hi haim770 :) I have added the code snippet... this is executed in the keyup method

Comment: Please update your question and make sure it contains a small repro of your situation, preferably in a Stack Snippet (on the editor toolbar). It'd also help if you pay some attention to formatting of your code, the easier it is to read the easier (and more inviting) it is to help. - Also, at any rate: have you tried using a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) yet?

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna need to register a custom [binding-handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to do that. Something like:

```
(function(ko)
{
     function handleAutoFit(textElement, val)
     {
        if (!textElement.value)
            textElement.value = val;

        var $textBox = $(textElement);
        var textElementOriginalHeight = $textBox.height();

        while ($textBox.height() > textElementOriginalHeight && textElement.scrollHeight < textElement.offsetHeight) {
            $textBox.height($textBox.height() - 1);
        }

        var h = 0;

        while (textElement.scrollHeight > textElement.offsetHeight && h !== textElement.offsetHeight) {
            h = textElement.offsetHeight;
            $textBox.height($textBox.height() + 1);
        }
     }

    ko.bindingHandlers.autoFit = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            handleAutoFit(element, val);
        }
    };
})(ko);
```

HTML:

```
<textarea data-bind="autoFit: someObservable, value: someObservable, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
```

Or if you're using the Knockout 3.1 and above:

```
<textarea data-bind="autoFit: someObservable, textInput: someObservable"></textarea>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ryr24dr/1/)

Comment: Hi haim770. This is great... but if you add a very long text 'this.name = ko.observable('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
}' initially it is not expanded. It would be great if it is initially taking the height of it's content

Comment: @user2726225 Then what?

Comment: Hi the edited comment is as above... sorry for the inconvenience :) (1st comment)

Comment: Hi haim770 :)... This is almost there... I think you mixed up update and init a bit... I think I can make this work so that the text area always takes the required height according to the available text... I will let you know soon :)

Comment: This is exactly what I want without the jquery library used :) http://jsfiddle.net/3p9bj/47/